# elastic search lost some data sometimes

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch.

We are seeing that sometimes elasticsearch loses some data,meaning something that was supposed to be indexed was actually not indexed .

Is this a known issue ? Can someone point me to links for some documentation ?

Comment: Can please explain more about your issue? Question is vague and very tough to address your issue. Usually elasticsearch won't delete any documents by itself.

Comment: @avr : So we have a point of sale application ,

the transaction's item(s) showing up in the sales view but the transaction doesnt should up in the receipts or any order level view
meaning it got into the item level index but not the order level index.When we do reindexing it solves the issue.

Comment: @Piyush Your question and the above comment are vague. You should provide more details or code snippets for the community to be able to help you. Furthermore,quoting you - "When we do reindexing it solves the issue." I suppose your code has some issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is really very bad. However may be you request data that isn't indexed yet - it can happen in case when you add new record to ES and immediately perform search to get it (not by id) - isn't it you case?